# synch css animation time ( from to )

Tags: css, animation, addclass, timing

http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7xpwa/

See code here ^

Basically I have a class that I am adding to a div that animates the background position, creating a moving stripe effect (like a barber pole). The class is added on a click event and as such, the start and stop of the background animation begins shortly after the click. When more than one div is used, they are usually out of synch. Is there a way to ensure that the animation of a second div clicked will be synchronous to the same animation on the first div clicked?

Thank you for your time!

code here as well:

CSS

```
.selected {

  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  25%, 
    transparent       25%, 
    transparent       50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  75%, 
    transparent       75%, 
    transparent
  );  

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    45deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  25%, 
    transparent       25%, 
    transparent       50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  75%, 
    transparent       75%, 
    transparent
  );  

    background: -o-linear-gradient(
    45deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  25%, 
    transparent       25%, 
    transparent       50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  75%, 
    transparent       75%, 
    transparent
  );  


      background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    45deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  25%, 
    transparent       25%, 
    transparent       50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  50%, 
    rgba(255,255,255, .95)  75%, 
    transparent       75%, 
    transparent
  );  


  animation: barberpole 2s linear infinite;

  -webkit-animation: barberpole 2s linear infinite;

  -moz-animation: barberpole 2s linear infinite;

/* opacity: .9;  */



}

@keyframes barberpole {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to   { background-position: 200px 100px; }
}


@-webkit-keyframes barberpole {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to   { background-position: 200px 100px; }
}


@-moz-keyframes barberpole {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to   { background-position: 200px 100px; }
}



.pixel {
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
float:left;
}
```

JS

```
$('.pixel').click(function(){

    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class='pixel'></div>
<div class='pixel'></div>
<div class='pixel'></div>
<div class='pixel'></div>
<div class='pixel'></div>
<div class='pixel'></div>
```

Comment: for instance is there a way to bind one elem's background to whatever some other one's is in realtime? I could have one div running the animation and then all others just referencing that one?

Comment: Have you tried the methods I listed?

Comment: @ZachSaucier unfortunately your methods are just theory... have a look at my answer for a practical and tested solution ;)

Comment: @webeno Since when does an answer require code? I've put all three methods into practice on different projects and know that each of them work. Providing exactly the exact code the OP needs is far from required

Comment: @ZachSaucier I don't think I said your answer _required_ code, I just said it's theory, and mine is practical, and both are facts. It's then the community's and the OP's to decide which one they like more / the best... ;)

Comment: @webeno Saying "unfortunately" and implying that my answer is not "practical and tested" means that it's a bad thing that I don't have code, suggesting your answer is superior simply for the fact that it has code which is a false claim. And what the community or OP likes more/best is completely irrelevant to whether or not an answer is correct or not.

Comment: @ZachSaucier hmm... yeah, my comment might have implied that, hope you believe me when i say, no offence intended... at the same time, i'm a practical guy, thus for me, yes, practical answers are, in this meaning, _better_ (certainly not _superior_) over theoretical answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying this for the last couple of hours, I found this challenging and fun, but I could not find the perfect solution.

I found no way of just following the previous animation so I needed to reset all `selected` classes and add them back.

The way I got this (somewhat) working was by using the `delay` function setting it to the same time as the animation, removing and re-adding the class immediately did not have the same effect unfortunately.

Here is what I came up with:

```
$('.pixel').click(function () {
    $('.pixel').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected').delay(2000).queue(function(){
                $(this).addClass('selected').dequeue();
            }); 
        }
    });
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7xpwa/9/

**EDIT**: I found it! Here is the full solution of the above trick (resetting the animation). It basically removes the element completely then re-adds it, this way resetting the animation:

```
$('.pixel').click(function () {
    $('.pixel').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            var elm = this,
                newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
            elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
        }
    });
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Source: [**Restart CSS Animation | CSS-TRICKS**](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7xpwa/10/

**EDIT #2**: In the comments of above article on CSS-TRICKS, I found an ever more simple way of doing the animation reset / element replacement as follows:

```
$('.pixel').click(function () {
    $('.pixel').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).clone(true)); // turned this into a 1 liner
        }
    });
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Another version of your fiddle with this: http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7xpwa/11/

Comment: wow! that's a pretty interesting way to handle it. Thanks for the time you put in.... I'm going to wait until I assign a 'winner' to this question. Hoping there something else possible.

Comment: this was a really good challenge... if you can figure out how to remove and add a class immediately, you're basically done! good luck! ;)

Comment: sorry for late response (took the weekend off from code) but that's amazing! Cool concepts being used too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can take.

**Fake it** - just cover up the original with a pseudo element or something and on click remove the overlay. The only downside to this is that the animations are still running when covered, but this shouldn't be an issue if you have are only animating a few elements. If you're animating a lot of elements you shouldn't be using CSS animations in the first place most likely

**Wait for [`animationIteration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationiteration)** - Check to see if the first is animated, if so start the other when `animationIteration` fires. The downside to this is that there will be a slight delay before the animations after the first start

**Keep track of the total animation time** - Start a timer when the first is clicked (or before), set animation-delay to a negative value syncing with the current time when the next are clicked. This is relatively difficult to do accurately.